# Declare a custom type for logical argument

Tags: typescript

preamble: I'm currently working on creating type definitions for existing js library;

The code I'm currently working with, uses a TON of approach like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  someMethod(product, label) {
    const productName = product.ownName || product.title || product;
    const labelId = labelIdNumber || label
  // do some stuff here
  }
}
```

This works fine for libraries purpose since it's possible to pass some object **or** a value (e.g string) directly.

However I'm having hard time to understand how to use generics properly in this case. I'm trying something like:

```
interface SomeClass {
  someMethod<T>(product: T, label: T): void
}
```

*In the future I will have interfaces to describe both `product` and `label` but for now I'm looking for some generic approach.*

I'm seeing at least one issue here:

```
const invalidArg = 123
SomeClass.someMethod(invalidArg); // No TS error because args type is generic (<T>)
```

So my question is how to create a `Type` that will state that the argument is `Object` or a `string`?

Basically I need a type that will do this

```
interface SomeClass {
  someMethod(product: Object | string, label: : Object | string): void
}
```

Why? Because this approach with `Object || string` is used all over the library and I would love to have some unique type for this and not writing `Object | string` 100 times

Comment: you can do `export type ObjectOrString = Object | string` in one of your `d.ts` files. and then `product: ObjectOrString`